# Python regex extract string between two braces, including new lines

Tags: python, regex

I have something like this

```
name {
    abc -> def{x};
    abc -> def{x};
    abc -> def{x};
    abc -> def;
    abc -> def;
    abc -> def;
}
```

I want to extract everything between the first and last braces {} so that the result looks like this

```
abc -> def{x};
abc -> def{x};
abc -> def{x};
abc -> def;
abc -> def;
abc -> def;
```

This is a different question because I am looking for everything between FIRST and LAST brackets.

Comment: I saw that post, it solves a different problem. I want everything between the FIRST and LAST

Comment: Marked for reopen then

Comment: Marked for reopen yet AGAIN